# Where do I get ncurses man pages from?

Tags: manpage, ncurses

I can't find the ncurses man pages even after:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to install also [`ncurses-doc`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ncurses-doc/). To install it from terminal run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ncurses-doc
```

Then you can read the manual page:

```
man ncurses
```

Comment: @Jake: because you, just like me, only looked up on `libncurses*` packages ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can also get the man page online:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ncurses

You can also use this link to search `http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=`. Just add your search to the end of that address.

Comment: OP didn't mention that raring was being used, it may be better to link to the search result page: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=ncurses You can also just search using the search box (without changing URLs)

Comment: @minerz029 the link was intentional, since the [documentation haven't changed](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/n/ncurses/ncurses_5.9-10ubuntu4/changelog)

Comment: For the common case that there is a page for the name in only one section, the URL for the most current version is http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ncurses

Answer (score 2):

Besides the mentioned `ncurses-doc` package, don't forget to install the examples!

## [ncurses-examples](http://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ncurses-examples) [image: Install ncurses-examples]

They are priceless... installed at `/usr/lib/ncurses/examples` and best viewed with `dwww`

Comment: I installed these examples but I where can I find their source code? Having the source code would be great for learning ncurses.

Comment: @Sergio , as with any other Debian package, source code can be found in their _source package_. Try `apt source ncurses-examples`, it will download `ncurses` source package containing all source code. Source for the examples can be found at `test/` subfolder.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason the `apt` command didn't work for me, but I installed with: `git clone https://github.com/gittup/ncurses.git` which includes the `test/` folder with the source code for the examples.

Comment: @Sergio, maybe `apt-get source ncurses` if you're using an Ubuntu older than 16.04. Yes, cloning the upstream (original author) repository may solve your problem for `ncurses`, but a general solution for _any_ Ubuntu package is to grab the source package using `apt`